# Dynamically add values of Editors in cshtml - mvc3

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using mvc3 asp.net and I have views in my project. In one of the view, I have fields like baseprice, etc.. And there is another total field as well. Is it feasible (through AJAX) to dynamically add these editor field values and display the result in another Editorfield (which, I would like to have as Read only).

cshtml code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Baseprice, new { @id = "Baseprice" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Baseprice)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmenitiesPrice)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmenitiesPrice, new { @id = "Amenity" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmenitiesPrice)
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookedAmount, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "BookedAmt" })
    <span runat="server" style="color:Red;" visible="false"> *</span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookedAmount)
</div>
```

Now, In the Ajax call inside the cshtml, I am trying to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Amenity').blur(function () {
            alert('Hi');
        });
        $('#carpark').blur(function () {
            $('#Baseprice').val = $('#carpark').val + $('#Amenity').val; 
        });
```

But, this function is never getting called on blur of either carpark or Amenity..

Am i missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. I should have written the ajax code as

$('#AmenitiesPrice').blur(function ()

and to get the value:

$('input#Baseprice').val...

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see #carpark in your html.
2. For getting value of input you need to add paranthesis and for setting value to input you need pass value as parametets like this:

   $('#Baseprice').val($('#carpark').val() + $('#Amenity').val());
3. You don't need to add `language="javascript"` to your script tag.
4. Try to use `@Html.TextBoxFor` insted of `@Html.EditorFor` because your new { @id = "Amenity" } parameter do not setting the id of element as Amenity, it stills #AmenitiesPrice.

When you calling

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmenitiesPrice, new { @id = "Amenity" })
```

you're using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) overload of EditorFor:

```
  public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    Object additionalViewData
)
```

So `new {@id = "Amenity"}` is additionalViewData that will be passed to veiw representing EditorTemplate for AmenitiesPrice type.

When you call

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AmenitiesPrice, new { @id = "Amenity" })
```

you're passing last parameter as htmlAttributes, so id of your input will be changed to #Amenity.

Alternative decision is to change selector to #AmenititsPrice:

```
$('#AmenititsPrice').blur(function () {
            alert('Hi');
        });
```